# Yahoo status detection

Tags: python, yahoo

Can anyone guide me How I can write a website to check yahoo messenger IDs availability (offline-online-invisible) ?
I mean something like `imvisible.info` and many more similar website ..
I would like to write it in python and I don't understand how I should start !?
Does Yahoo have any standard API or something like that for me ?

Please give me the code which I should use in my website to get an ID availability or at least some link about my problem .. :)
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Python Package index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) has [several packages](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=yahoo&submit=search) that deal with Yahoo.

You can also check .

1. [Yahoo messenger IM SDK](http://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/guide/chapterintrotomessengersdk.html).